# Anaconda error while installing pytorch on windpws

Tags: pytorch, anaconda3

I am running anaconda on windows; When i try to install pytorch in the anaconda prompt I get the following error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision'

i checked the openssl version via conda list and it is 1.1.g3
I also moved the lib crypto and libssl from the anaconda/library/bin to anaconda3/DLLs (as per one the prior solutions.

What could be the issue? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use the commands given in the official pytorch website. Or you can use pip to install too. Commands for both conda and pip are given in pytorch website.

Comment: Tried what is on pytorch website. The issues still remains. Appears to be an ssl issue on anaconda.  I tried setting the proxy server too,but still does not work